nghttp2_option_set_no_rfc9113_leading_and_trailing_ws_validation could not be located in the dynamic link library php-8.3.4\ext\php_curl.dll
While I am starting apache server from laragon on windows I am getting this error:
The procedure entry point nghttp2_option_set_no_rfc9113_leading_and_trailing_ws_validation could not be located in the dynamic link library F:\laragon\bin\php\php-8.3.4-Win32-vs16-x64\ext\php_curl.dll

As it is saying it can't locate the the dynamic link lybrary in F:\laragon\bin\php\php-8.3.4-Win32-vs16-x64\ext\php_curl.dll. But the file is there.
I tried to set the exact location in the php.ini file but did not work.
; The ldap extension must be before curl if OpenSSL 1.0.2 and OpenLDAP is used
; otherwise it results in segfault when unloading after using SASL.
; See https://github.com/php/php-src/issues/8620 for more info.
;extension=ldap

extension=F:\laragon\bin\php\php-8.3.4-Win32-vs16-x64\ext\php_curl.dll
;extension=ffi
;extension=ftp


A simple Google search gives this.

On my end, I just updated with the latest Apache version. based on this.

I had the same problem, I am using Laragon I can choose my Apache, PHP, MySQL versions respectively. I am trying to develop a project using latest Laravel version (Laravel 11), I have updated my PHP version to 8.3.7, and using MySQL 5.7.44, and facing this issue. All I did was just go to Apache downloads and updated my Apache version. It is all good now. Go ahead and try this to see if it works for you.
Sincerely,
Irfandev.

I had the same problem and after a lot of research it's the version of apache that needs to be changed! This youtuber explains it well, even if I don't speak this language:https://youtu.be/fXkmqoZeaGU?si=B0_jZd69DpS-w78e

While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - From Review

php_curl.dll have problem with old version of apache. to fix just upgrade your apache version. If you are on windows and use xampp. just upgrade xampp version. for me upgrading to xampp ver 8.2.12 /  control panel v 3.3.0 solved problem.

How is this answer different from the accepted answer?

I got the same problem, but along with

"libssh2_session_set_read_timeout" was not found in DLL "C:\xampp\php\ext\php_curl.dll"

I resolved the issue using the method described above.
https://github.com/php/php-src/issues/16794#issuecomment-2476165187
So the "nghttp2_option_set_no_rfc9113_leading_and_trailing_ws_validation" issue could be solved with the same logic.
Just copy the nghttp2.dll under php folder, then use it to replace the one under apache/bin, everything would just work perfectly.

It seems that there is a problem with the php_curl.dll file contained in PHP version 8.3.6. To resolve the issue, copy the file contained in version 8.1.2 to replace. The folder path is: php-8.3.6-Win32-vs16-x64\ext.
